# JasperReport 4.1.2 - Using complex Java Bean and subreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm facing a problem when trying to generate a report based on some java bean's.

Suppose I have this configuration: a master bean, say

> **Bean1**
>
> - String name
> - String age
> - ArrayList bean2
>
> **Bean2**
>
> - String text
> - ArrayList
>
> **Bean3** is the last child of the tree and it is composed by:
>
> - String text

(I have more levels but this is enough for you to understand)
I'm using SubReport component to access data inside every `ArrayList` of a bean and it works well (using JRBeanCollectionDataSource()).

The problem is that, at `Bean3`, I have acess to all text fields of **every** `Bean2`. For example: I have an `ArrayList<Bean2>` of size 2: `bean2_1` and `bean2_2`.
`bean2_1` has an `ArrayList<Bean3>` of size 2 and `bean2_2` has an `ArrayList` of size 3.

When I print the content of `Bean3` (field `text`) for `bean2_1` and `bean2_2`, it shows all 5 text values for all my beans: `bean2_1` and `bean2_2`.
Anyone had already faced this problem? How can i bind the differente levels to show only the correct data??

Can anyone help ?